# How to resolve a 'smtp.ServicePoint.Address threw an exception of type System.NotSupportedException' when sending emails in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, smtp

I am trying to send emails through an MVC App. Everything else seems to be working fine except for `smtp.Send(mess)`.

The error description is below:

> smtp.ServicePoint.Address threw an exception of type System.NotSupportedException

My code:

```
    var smtp = new SmtpClient
                    {
                        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                        Port = 587,
                        EnableSsl = true,
                        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail.Address, password)
                    };
                using (var mess = new MailMessage(senderEmail, receiverEmail)
                {
                    Subject = subject,
                    Body = body
                })
                {
                    smtp.Send(mess); 
                }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that the port is correct? look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701158/sending-e-mail-by-smtpclient-causes-system-invalidoperationexception-in-system

Comment: have exactly same problem and no idea... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint.address?view=netcore-3.1 here it said NotSupportedException is caused by ServicePoint in host mode.... and in the sourcecode https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/Net/ServicePoint.cs it also has  " 
internal Uri InternalAddress
        {
            get
            {
                GlobalLog.Assert(!m_HostMode, "ServicePoint#{0}::InternalAddress|Can't be used in Host Mode.", ValidationHelper.HashString(this)); "

Comment: my true issue is wrong port number... maybe the above exception doesn't hurt...

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the web.config file in my project and find out mail is physically strode in the pickupDirectoryLocation="D:\xxxxmaildrop" location and there is no any "xxxxmaildrop" folder in my D drive. So manually created a one. Then run the project.
After that step a mail was created in the given location and no exceptions found. Please try this solution too, it worked for me.

> ```
> <mailSettings>
>       <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" from="no-reply@xxxx.xx">
>         <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="D:\xxxxmaildrop" />
>       </smtp>
> </mailSettings>
> ```

Comment: this method only work if the smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory"